# convert string list to decimal list to 10 decimal points in python

Tags: python-3.x

How to convert folowing list:

```
['524.7940719572', '0.1874483617', '0.0321140582', '228.8002278843', '6843.5984811891', '29.9108027316', '60.2048797607', '220.7372120052', '556.828334181']
```

to:

```
[524.7940719572, 0.1874483617, 0.0321140582, 228.8002278843, 6843.5984811891, 29.9108027316, 60.2048797607, 220.7372120052, 556.828334181] in python
```

Comment: try, `[float(i) for i in list_contains_strings]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    l = ['524.7940719572', '0.1874483617', '0.0321140582', '228.8002278843', '6843.5984811891', '29.9108027316', '60.2048797607', '220.7372120052', '556.828334181']
    i = 0
    for v in l:
        l[i] = float(v)
        i = i+1
    print l
```

results the following output:

```
    [524.7940719572, 0.1874483617, 0.0321140582, 228.8002278843, 6843.5984811891, 29.9108027316, 60.2048797607, 220.7372120052, 556.828334181]
```